# Echo date range on different version of php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$listData2 = [];
$start     = new DateTime('2017-01-01');
$end       = (new DateTime('2017-01-12'))->modify('+1 day');
$interval  = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period    = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $index => $period1)
{ echo  $listData2[] =  $period1->format("d/m/Y"); }
```

Hi, I found the below code to output my dates from 01/01/2017 until 12/01/2017 and it's working fine. I used the code above on PHP 5.5 However, when I copy this code to a different computer using PHP 5.3, there's lot of error. How do I change the above code so that it's compatible with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by not using `[]` for arrays and initializing your date object and then manipulating it. Will work down to 5.3.0 - [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7aa2340498ca6a73b3d9b9d69146c8e8be15b33)

```
<?php
$listData2 = array();
$start     = new DateTime('2017-01-01');
$end       = new DateTime('2017-01-12');
$end       = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval  = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period    = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $index => $period1) {
    echo $listData2[] = $period1->format("d/m/Y");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com.
This `(new DateTime('2017-01-12'))->modify('+1 day');` causing

```
syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
```

**Solution**

Just move `modify('+1 day')`.

```
<?php
$listData2 = array();
$start     = new DateTime('2017-01-01');
$end       = new DateTime('2017-01-12');
$interval  = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period    = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end->modify('+1 day'));

foreach ($period as $index => $period1)
{ echo  $listData2[] =  $period1->format("d/m/Y") . "<br/>"; }
```

Just test it here if you want: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32f0fed1fb0c89c7bd3dff0ed21f9178ecca